# Regex use in BeautifulSoup's find

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use regex in a `find` command. I want to find a tag span which text contains 'example'.

I've already tried this:

```
place = infoFrame.find('span',text = re.compile('.*example.*:'))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 're' referenced before assignment
```

Which is quite weird because I have `import re` written on the top of the page. The line I wrote above is in a function of a class.

I know that it is another way - find all `span` tags an then check for each tag whether it contains `'example'` but I'm curious how to do it using `regex` inside the `find` command.

Can you give me an advice what is wrong?

Comment: *Elsewhere* in your function you are using `re = ...`. E.g. you are using `re` as a local variable *too*. Rename that local variable.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Lot of thanks. I had 'import re' already under this code. That was problem.

Answer (score 1):

*Elsewhere* in your function you are using `re = ...` or `import re`. E.g. you are using `re` as a local variable *too*. Rename or remove that local variable:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<span>example: foo</span>')
>>> def find_span():
...     return soup.find('span', text=re.compile('.*example.*:'))
...     re = 'oops'
... 
>>> find_span()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in find_span
UnboundLocalError: local variable 're' referenced before assignment
>>> def find_span():
...     return soup.find('span', text=re.compile('.*example.*:'))
... 
>>> find_span()
<span>example: foo</span>
```

Your use of `re.compile()` is otherwise fine; you can remove the first `.*` pattern though, and avoid the catastrophic backtracking problem. For any element with a lot of text and *no* `example` text in it, the pattern will be exceedingly slow otherwise. Make the second `*` non-greedy by using `?`:

```
place = infoFrame.find('span', text=re.compile('example.*?:'))
```